# Bluetooth communication not working with DC power but works with USB power?

Tags: serial, power, bluetooth, softwareserial

I am running an HM-10 Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) module to transmit serial data (using SoftwareSerial) from an analog sensor onboard my Arduino Uno to a serial terminal app on my Android phone. When I power the Arduino with a USB power bank, the data transmits flawlessly.

When I tried to power the Arduino with a 9V battery through the DC power jack instead of USB power, the BLE module connects to my phone, but no data is transmitted when a serial connection is established.

Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: "9V battery" as in little wimpy PP3 that can't power ****?

Comment: @Majenko yes, correct. Is the implication of your reply that the (brand new) battery is not powerful enough? If so I could try to source a battery box to attempt to get it running on AA batteries as a test.

Comment: PP3 batteries are the laughing stock of the battery world. You want at least 6V of AA batteries  for what you are doing - and if you value your battery life you want to bypass the Arduino's on-board regulators and use switching regulators instead.

Comment: @Majenko thanks! I am putting the Arduino onboard a drone and it'll only need to work for 10 mins at a time; the biggest concern is weight and not battery time. But I will give it a try.

Comment: In that case you would be better using Li-Ion batteries since they have a higher energy density for their size/weight.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks - so there is no practical reason other than a lack of power being supplied to the unit that the 9V PP3 would not cause the SoftwareSerial data to be sent?

Comment: Transmitting takes a lot of power. The Duracell datasheets consider 250mA to be a heavy load (it's the heaviest they characterise it for). Transmitting typically takes hundreds of mA, and needs it delivering rapidly - something a PP3 is not good at due to the massive (comparatively) internal resistance.

Comment: @Majenko - BLE transmit power is a brief pulse at a few tens of milliamps.  It's within the capability of a CR2032 *coin cell*.  Advertising fairly frequently mine drew an average of around 200 uA.  Likely the Arduino draws more, at least on average.

Comment: @ChrisStratton A well designed one is, yes. A cheap HM-10 from China? Who knows what that might draw. I wouldn't trust it to be less than a few hundred milliamps.

Comment: What I measured *was* an HM-10.  Running essentially the TI example.  Not sure if there's any software in them by default.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Also a CR2032 isn't crippled by the linear regulators of the Arduino throwing away about 50% of the power of the battery.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As a general rule of thumb though - PP3 + LDO + Transmitter (of any kind) = a bad mix. Change the PP3 for something with more grunt and less voltage, or swap the LDO for an efficient switcher, and things improve massively.

Comment: As a "quick fix" you could try "buffering" the power to the HM-10 with a large electrolytic capacitor (in the order of hundreds or thousands of µF).

Comment: Your whole line of reasoning here is based on a grossly erroneous guess at what these things draw.  Check the TI data sheet  if you don't want to believe me.

Comment: No it isn't. I don't give a damn what they draw. A PP3 on an Arduino with the wildly inefficient LDO can barely power itself and maybe an LED. Add even a low power transmitter and you're asking for trouble.

Comment: There are exactly two scenarios that account for "it works on usb but not battery". One is they forgot to connect the grounds between two parts of their circuit, and ground is making its way through a convoluted route via the computer. That is not the case here, since it works with a nice powerful USB powerbank. So it must be the second scenario, which is attempting to use a PP3 battery, instantly confirmed by the OP. Ergo, improve the battery and/or the regulation, and fix the problem.

Comment: It may be that the BLE is actually functioning fine but some other unspecified part of the setup is failing. It's impossible to tell from here. Suffice it to say, though, the battery is the cause of the problem, and has been many times before on Arduinos.

Answer (score 0):

Take two 9 volt batteries with same specifications and connect it into the parallel by using this efficiency of current increases and it full fill the current requirement at the time of data transmission and for others modules u r using with the arduino.

Comment: While this likely wouldn't meet the OP's design requirements, it's a perfectly reasonable benchtop test to confirm that the 9v batter is (or isn't) the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A PP3 battery is not a suitable power source for an Arduino.

For battery powered operations I would recommend a set of AA batteries with between 6 and 8 volts (if you don't care about bulk) or a Li-Ion battery (or two) and a suitable buck or boost (depending on number of cells) regulator to bypass the inefficient linear regulators on the Arduino.